# How to resolve Dell Poweredge 2850 boot error

Tags: dell-poweredge

In the POST sequence I get the error message

29160 at slot 2 0A:03:00 scsi controller config error. 02

I removed the CDrom drive, could this be the cause? Where do I look to find out whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Adaptec, hope it helps;

SCSI Controller Configuration Error 02
This applies to the following Product(s): Adaptec SCSI Card 39160, Adaptec SCSI Card 29160, Adaptec SCSI Card 29160LP, Adaptec SCSI Card 29160N, Adaptec SCSI Card 19160

**Answer** This error message will appear when connecting an HVD (High Voltage Differential) SCSI device to the Low Voltage Differential (LVD) SCSI card. Ultra 160 SCSI cards only support the use of Low Voltage Differential (LVD) and Single-Ended (SE) devices. CAUTION! Connecting HVD devices to a non-HVD SCSI controller may damage both the device and the SCSI controller.

Determine if your device(s) being attached is a HVD device. Check for any markings on the device, typically near the SCSI connector that may indicate HVD or LVD/SE. However do not trust these marking completely, double check the type of device inside the unit. Although the external case may be marked as LVD, it is still possible the internal device may still be an HVD device.